# How to use pipe to assign a variable

Tags: bash, pipe, variable

How can I assign value of $x1+$x2 to bc by piping? here in my code $bc holds no value.

```
echo -n 'value x1 : '
read x1
echo -n 'value x2 : '
read x2
echo $x1+$x2 | bc
echo $bc
```

Comment: Checkout the `bash` man page section on "Command Subsitution".

Comment: Say i choose 5 and 12 as the numbers: Are you trying to get the total in the variable bc (`17`) or are you trying to get the string (`5+12` )?

Comment: `x1=4; x2=3; x=$((x1+x2)); echo $x`

Comment: What does piping have to do with it? It sounds like you just want to assign the result of `$x1+$x2` to a variable, and you somehow decided piping is the right way to do that

Comment: General note: Piping means forwarding the output of a previous command as the input of the next command, e.g. echo 1,2,3 separated by tabs and then cut to display the first column only: `cat -e 1\\t2\\t3 | cut -f1 `. For assigning the output of a command to a variable, use `variable=$( command )`

Answer (score 2):

is easy and there are many ways to do, for example

```
v=$(echo $x1+$x2 | bc)  
v=`echo $x1+$x2 | bc`
```

Note that `bc` is integer arithmetics only and that you need `bc -l` for a proper math library. Note that you can skip the echoing with the 'here' redirection `<<<` for strings:

```
v=$( bc <<< $x1+$x2 )
```

Comment: Backquotes are exactly equivalent to capturing parens, but they don't nest and they're harder to read.  Avoid them except for interactive use if you find it easier to type them.